# Call to a member function success() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have tried many times this error in different ways also tried one sollution from: [CakePHP: Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876791/cakephp-call-to-a-member-function-setflash-on-a-non-object]) url ... But this solution is also not working in my project.

Cant recognize whats the error. !!!

Here is my User.php model

```
class User extends AppModel {

public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
public $components = array('Email','Flash','Session');


 public function send_mail($useremail){

    $Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');

    $Email->emailFormat('html')
          ->from('abc@xyz.com')
          ->to($useremail)
          ->subject('User subject');
    if($Email->send("123")){
        $this->Flash->success(__('Mail Sent')); // **this line cause error**
    }else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('Problem during sending email');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try this $this->Flash->success("Mail Sent");

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation suggest, **FlashComponent** provides two ways to set flash messages: its `__call()`magic method and its 
`set()` method. To furnish your application with verbosity, FlashComponent’s `__call()` magic method allows you use a method name that maps to an element located under the `src/Template/Element/Flash directory`. By convention, camelcased methods will map to the lowercased and underscored element name:

> // Uses src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp

```
$this->Flash->success('This was successful');
```

> // Uses src/Template/Element/Flash/great_success.ctp

```
$this->Flash->greatSuccess('This was greatly successful');
```

Alternatively, to set a **plain-text message** without rendering an element, you can use the set() method:

```
$this->Flash->set('This is a message');
```

And hence, you need to change it by typing

```
 $this->Flash->success('Mail sent');
```

Comment: Dear friend. thank you for your valuable suggestions ... I tried all the suggestion that you mentioned , but not a single one is working !!! .. Lets say if i use $this->Flash->set() then it generates set() on a non-object error ; vice versa for success it generates success() on a non-object error !!!

Comment: @MrudangShah try adding this statment in the class user 
`App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');` and lemme know, if it works.